# Angular and Spring-Boot (Spring Security): .subscribe() on service http.post call not working properly

Tags: angular, spring-boot, subscribe

I'm still quite new to Angular and really don't know what is going on with my app.

Situation: I have a custom login screen (very simple, just two inputs and the submit). There is an Angular-Service to send a POST-Request containing of a DTO with just a username/mail and password to the back-end (Spring-Boot). The posting itself works perfectly fine, but the Rest-Controller answers with a ResponseEntity wrapping a User-Object and Code 200, if the authentication worked or a null-Object and 401, if the authentication failed.

As far as I can tell, the backend-logic works, but listening to the response via subscribe on the return of the frontend-service is very confusing:

1. When I send wrong credentials, it triggers the error-function of the subscribe.. But just sometimes (seems random, but I don't know)..
2. When I enter the right credentials, nothing ever happens at all. Neither in the next-function, nor in the completed-function.

I really hope, someone can give a hint on what I'm doing wrong..
Thank you so much in advance!

Code (Be aware: Groovy):

Backend-Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    HttpEntity<User> isLoggedIn(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        try {

            ...

            println(new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK))
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK)
        } catch (InvalidCredentialsException ignore) {
            println(new ResponseEntity<User>(null, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(null, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
        }
    }
```

The Controller itself works fine, here is the println-output of a valid call:

```
<200 OK OK,User{id=1, mail='any.user@gmail.com', username='User', password='$2a$10$QVusyLr0is6dAReTv6CNOObgQHluR173Ynx4YgT25zAzwK5R6CKi6', role=null, description='null'},[]>
```

Invalid Call:

```
<401 UNAUTHORIZED Unauthorized,[]>
```

Here is the front-end angular-service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  private apiBaseUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public logIn(request: LoginRequest): Observable<User> {
    return this.httpClient.post<User>(this.apiBaseUrl + "/api/auth/login", request)
  }
}
```

The LoginRequest-Interface:

```
export interface LoginRequest {
  userCredential: string
  password: string
}
```

The User-Interface:

```
export interface User {
  id: number
  mail: string
  username: string
  password: string
  role?: string
  description?: string
}
```

Aaand here is the part, where I'm completely lost in space, the login-component.ts:

```
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  handleLogin(username: string, password: string) {

    const loginRequest: LoginRequest = {
      userCredential: username,
      password: password
    }

    this.userService.logIn(loginRequest).subscribe(
      (user: User) => {
        window.alert("Hello")
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        window.alert("No User found")
      },
      () => {
        window.alert("Completed")
      }
    )
  }
```

As mentioned before, the "No User found" triggers seemingly random and both other triggers haven't worked even once (Even, if the credentials were right (See above println of ResponseEntity)).

I've already tried to get a User via get-call, which worked perfectly; so I personally don't think, the User-Interface is the problem.

I don't think that here is the issue, because obviously the attributes are sent into the backend correctly, but here is the matching .html:

```
<div style="margin: 10px">
  <form>
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Username or Mail</td>
        <td><input class="authInput" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username or Mail" #username></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input class="authInput" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" #password></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input class="authSubmit" type="submit" id="submitLogin" name="submitLogin" value="Log in" (click)="handleLogin(username.value, password.value)"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

If you need any further details, just ask.

Thanks again!!!

Comment: What is the actual return of a successful login attempt? So when you inspect it in the browser network console? I wonder if what you are returning is JSON..?

Comment: Hmmm I can't find any returning entry tbh. Maybe there is a problem with the data coming back? 

When the login fails, there is an "login" entry, which has `{"userCredential":"asda","password":"sd"}` in its payload, but the answer tab is empty, as well ...

Comment: You should also make your button (in the template) `type="button"` because the default behavior of the form element, when you click on the submit button is to issue a GET request to whatever the current URL is. That might not be something you want, given that you handle the button click yourself.

Comment: You are a absolute genius!!!!! Thank you so much that worked! :)
At least partly: The user is given to the front end now, but it still just works every let's say second time -.-

Comment: I am glad it helped you. While we are at this, please keep in mind that the default `type` for the `<button>` is `submit` if you don't override it by specifying the `type` property yourself.

Comment: You are insane a second time :,D I changed the type to "button" and now it works every f*ckn time! I love you, I tried everything for at least 10 hours!! <3

Can I mark your comment as the solution? I can't find it anywhere ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think your server is wrapping the User in a ResponseEntity object (whatever the heck that is - not a groovy dev).  So it's not just returning a user.

Your http service is expecting a User, not what it's actually getting back.

To test this theory, modify your service to return an any:

```js
public logIn(request: LoginRequest): Observable<User> {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.apiBaseUrl + "/api/auth/login", request)
  }
```

And in your component make this related change:

```js
this.userService.logIn(loginRequest).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        console.log(result);
        debugger;
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        window.alert("No User found")
      }
    )
```

Then use your debugging skills to spelunk into the result and see what it actually is.  Finally, adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: First: thanks a lot for your answer!

ResponseEntity is not Groovy specific, it is a wrapper for any object, as well as a HttpCode.
See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

I tried your changes out, but there is still nothing happening.
Imo it is also very strange that with wrong credentials the error triggers, but not all the time -.-

But thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Well, when you say you tried my changes out, do you mean that you ran this with Chrome dev tools open, and that it stopped at your debugger line, and that you were able to see the object returned?  My code was not an answer for you, but rather how you can get the answer yourself.

Comment: Also, I should say, that if it's not stopping at your the debugger line, then the service is not returning correctly.  Examining the error object may be more illuminating.